# AppInventor Extension block with predefined value

Tags: app-inventor

I'm trying to create an extension with pre-defined value (for example string or int), which would be “sticked” to function in block menu, something like in picture bellow. 
I have no idea how to write it in Java, or whether it is even possible.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mmH1.jpg)
[image]

You can see that string is connected to main block in block menu.

Comment: let me recommend you to ask questions about working with the App Inventor sources in the Open Source community here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/c/open-source-development/10

Comment: I don't think, that these predefined values are possible for extensions...